# Apache2 ldap authorization with dynamic group name based on server name

Tags: apache2

I have multiple VirtualHosts and some of them require authorization. I have one config that I include in those hosts that handles basic authentication. I would like apache to lookup group based on server name
I've tried

```
Require ldap-group cn=%{SERVER_NAME},ou=Groups,dc=example,dc=com
```

but unfortunately the variable is not resolved. Any tips?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is spaces between identifiers, so

```
Require ldap-group cn=%{SERVER_NAME}, ou=Groups, dc=example, dc=com
```

[See example 5](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_authnz_ldap.html#examples) in the official documentation

Comment: Nice, although it's odd if the spaces are really important here. The docs show them but don't say that they're required. Also, this answers an old question: [Dynamically Authenticate Apache with LDAP Based on Request String?](https://serverfault.com/questions/289569/dynamically-authenticate-apache-with-ldap-based-on-request-string/1052381#1052381)